# Long wait times logging in as other user using sudo

Tags: sudo

Any clues to why it takes 20-30 seconds for me to log in using sudo+su?

```
$ time sudo su ida -l
exit
ida@timbuktu:~$ exit
logout

real    0m18.076s

$ time sudo su ida
exit
ida@timbuktu:/home/carl-erik$ exit
exit

real    0m25.082s
```

This is quite frustrating when changing users frequently to do work. I might add that this might not be strictly restrictred to `sudo`, as logging in using ssh also takes approx 25 seconds.

The contents of these files were requested. They are unaltered.

**/etc/nsswitch.conf**

```
passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat

hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns mdns4
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       myhostname.myisp.net       myhostname
192.168.10.2    myhostname.hopto.org

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: What do `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/nsswitch.conf` contain?

Comment: Added. I haven't changed anything from install, except editing the actual hostnames for fake ones when posting here